# Redirect to a particular URL after clicking anywhere on an Android WebView

Tags: android, click, touch, android-webview

I am creating a webview application such that. The application layout has WebView stacked over another WebView; it means essentially there are two webviews in the layout.

Now what I want is - When a user clicks anywhere on the 2nd webview (which is at bottom) a new activity with new layout opens loading a particular URL.

Any Ideas??

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you click on the 2nd webview, do you replace the entire view (top and bottom) with a new activity, or are you just loading a new URL into the bottom?

Comment: I want to replace the entire view with a new activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to touch listeners instead of clicks like this:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebViewId);

webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://myurl.com");
          Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
          startActivity(launchBrowser);
          return true;
    }
});
```